# Кодировка ResponseBody

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, кодировка

`@ResponseBody` при формировании ответа использует `StringHttpMessageConverter`(исправьте, если не прав). И у него по-умолчанию кодировка **ISO-8859-1**. Соответственно, чтобы клиент мог принять ответ в кодировке **utf-8**, недостаточно просто поставить фильтр, который бы устанавливал кодировку ответа(`ResponseBody` перезаписывает ее на свою дефолтную). Я вижу три варианта:

1) Самый прямолинейный: просто указать кодировку с помощью `produces` в `@RequestMapping`. Этот способ не нравится, потому что все ответы должны быть в **utf-8**, а значит ее надо будет указывать вручную на все обрабочтики с аннотацией `@ResponseBody`

2) Изменить дефолтную кодировку mvc контекста на этапе инициализации:

```
@Override
public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
for (HttpMessageConverter converter : converters) {
    if (converter instanceof StringHttpMessageConverter) {
        ((StringHttpMessageConverter) converter).setDefaultCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    }
}
```

Хотя это делает то, что мне нужно, я не до конца понимаю, как это может повлиять на работу фреймворка. Не сломаю ли я таким образом что-нибудь. Да и cast вверх выглядит некрасиво

3) Этот способ еще не пробовал, но думаю, такое возможно: установить `HandlerInterceptor` (или аспект), который бы конвертировал ответ от обработчиков в **utf-8**, если кодировка ответа другая. Покрывает минусы первого и второго способов, но производит нагрузку, будучи лишним этапом между сервером и клиентом.

Изучая спринг до этого, мне начало казаться, что он способен предоставить решение для любой не касающейся бизнес-логики задачи. Но тут кажется, что это не предусмотрено. Или я плохо искал? Есть варант по-лучше, и если нет, какой лучший из описанных?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы можете просто объявить тот же самый `StringHttpMessageConverter` в своей конфигурации с нужной Вам кодировкой. Один из конструкторов `StringHttpMessageConverter` принимает параметр `Charset defaultCharset`. Объявляете бин с типом HttpMessageConverter и возвращаете `new StringHttpMessageConverter(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`. Либо используете любой другой удобный конвертер.

Spring Boot автоматически конфигурирует `StringHttpMessageConverter` с кодировкой UTF-8

Comment: Спасибо, добавить с помощью конфигурации конвертер получилось. Но если сделать конвертер бином, то кодировка не меняется. Мне то без разницы, проблема решена) но может есть какие-то уточнения насчет способа с бином? Может это spring boot'овское?